Error in Di Francesco et al "Conformal Field theory" Eq 9.119?
In deriving equation 9.119 in their book the authors appear to claim that the metric variation of the Ricci tensor obeys
$$
g^{\mu\nu} \delta R_{\mu\nu}= (\frac 12 g_{\mu\nu}\nabla^2- \nabla_\mu\nabla_\nu) \delta g^{\mu\nu}
$$
but  Callan and Coleman in their famous New Improved Energy-Momentum tensor  paper (Annals
of Physics Vol 59 (1970) 42-73) seem to find
$$  
g^{\mu\nu} \delta R_{\mu\nu}\stackrel{?}{=} ( g_{\mu\nu}\nabla^2- \nabla_\mu\nabla_\nu) \delta g^{\mu\nu},
$$
and on doing the calculation I get the same as them.
This makes
$$
T^{(1)}_{\mu\nu}\stackrel{?}{=} -\frac \gamma{2\pi} (\partial_\mu\partial_\nu\varphi  -\eta_{\mu\nu}\partial^\sigma \partial_\sigma \varphi)
$$
which, lacking the 1/2 in their formula
$$
T^{(1)}_{\mu\nu}{=} -\frac \gamma{2\pi} \left(\partial_\mu\partial_\nu\varphi  -\frac 12 \eta_{\mu\nu}\partial^\sigma \partial_\sigma \varphi\right)
$$
is not traceless.  The tracelessness seems important for Eq 9.30 and its consequences. Am I missing something obvious?

I haven't read Di Francesco but I have done this calculation and I agree with callan and you.

@ Noone Thanks!
